Entity Framework Core Cosmos DB - expression cannot be evaluated
I'm using VS17.10.5 Net 8, Blazor server side.
I have an EF Core context with a simple data class Person (id, name, address, phone) that is set up to point to a Cosmos DB database.
When I call SaveChanges() to save to Cosmos DB, I am getting an error message

The expression cannot be evaluated. A common cause of this error is attempting to pass a lamda into a delegate.

My code is as follows:
Person p = new Person() {id = 1, Name="bob", Address="someAddr", Phone="123", PartitionKey="/person"}
dbContext.Add(p);
dbContext.SaveChanges(); <-- exception


Check whether the Person class is correctly configured for EF Core and Cosmos DB. Specifically, verify that the PartitionKey property is set up correctly or not.

Probably due to setting id to a numeric value (1), given that a document's id must be a string.

You want to save id, name, address and phone but in your code it shows you are also trying to save PartitionKey="/person". Once check with the Person class whether it consists of all the data which you want to save.

Actually two errors: 1) saving id as numeric instead of string, and 2) setting the value of the partition key to a property path (it needs to be a value, not a path - partition key path is set when you create the container and can't be specified on a per-document basis)

Thanks, the id is now a string and the partition key is correct.  I have an azure function writing into a different container, the difference between the two is here I use EF Core.
I am perplexed why the exception type being returned is a DbUpdate exception when I am doing an Add.  Also, the error code is 404, substatus 0.

Solution To my question
For some reason, EF Core isn't appearing to support database first for Cosmos DB.
I needed to make a to Ensure created before executing the code.
dbContext.Databse.EnsureCreated()

This took the entity (builder) definitions in OnModelCreating() in the context and created the Cosmos Containers as required.
Because I was using the Blazor template, it also required that I implement the schema for the IdentityDbContext which required adding 7 identity entities into 2 additional containers (due to partition key constraints).
